# Is there a Designer OpenGL Widget for QT5?

Tags: opengl, qt-creator, qt5

I am migrating some code from FLTK to QT5 and I can't seem to get a widget in the graphical designed that corresponds to an OpenGL context? Does such a widget exist?

I built QT from the official sources, targeting VS2012x64 with the OpenGL option and have tried to add `QT += opengl` to my project.pro file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt has the QGLWidget, but you should not use that directly in the Designer. Instead you should place a *layout* where you want the OpenGL widget to appear. Then you subclass QGLWidget, as you must overwrite the `paintGL` function anyway to draw something. Then after the `setupUI()` call you instanciate your custom GL widget and add it to the layout you placed in the designer with `layoutinstance->addWidget(…)`

#### update due to comment

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>335</width>
    <height>191</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionQuit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>&amp;Quit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

myglwidget.hh

```
#include <QGLWidget>

class MyGLWidget : public QGLWidget
{ //...
};
```

mainwindow.hh

```
#include <QMainWindow>

#include "myglwidget.hh"
#include "mainwindow_ui.hh" // generated by uic

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow
{

    MainWindow(QObject *parent = NULL) : 
        QMainWindow(parent)
    { // one would implement the constructor in the .cc file of course
        this->setupUi(this);
    
        glwidget = new MyGLWidget(this);

        // using the this pointer to emphase the location of the
        // member variable used.
        // NOTE: In the UI we defined a layout names verticalLayout
        this->verticalLayout->addWidget(glwidget);
    }

protected:
    MyGLWidget *glwidget;
};
```

The key is, that you use just a layout. An ordinary, regular layout in the UI, to which you add your derived OpenGL widget. No morphs, no promotions in the ui!

Comment: I am having some trouble realize this scheme. I inserted a `vertical layout` I morph it into a `QWidget`. Then I go tot `promote` and I cannot see a base class called `QGLWidget`. If my `objectName` is `mVerticleWidget` how do I subclass?

Comment: @Mikhail: No, not that way! Give me a minute, I'm going to prepare some example code.

Comment: @Mikhail: Note that this works the same way for both Qt-4.x and Qt-5.x

Comment: I can't seem to find a <QGLWidget>, is this part of QT5? My pro file looks like `QT += core gui opengl`

Comment: @Mikhail: Yes it is. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/qglwidget.html

Comment: Weird I needed to do `#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>` but I am having some other problems with this kind of setup.